# Синонимизация меток на тему [сериализация]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [serialization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization). Надо бы её синонимизировать с меткой [сериализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Кстати, у нас есть ещё много меток, так или иначе связанных с темой сериализации: поищите метки по запросу `serializ`.

Comment: Рифма в заголовке хорошая получилась

Answer (score 2):

Добавил синонимов:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]